# How do I use GET /channels/{channel.id}/messages

Tags: discord.py

I want to make a bot to search through a channel and find a random message by a user. To do that, I need to read past messages. I've looked in the documentation and all it says is GET /channels/{channel.id}/messages.

I'm asking: How could I return the contents of a message and the author of the message (if possible).

Comment: Have you looked through the discord API documentation or the discord.py documentation? Discord.py is a python API Wrapper for the Discord API, which you should definitely use when trying to create bots, because it's much simpler and easier.

Comment: Your label says that you are using `discord.py` but there is more information needed before we can answer.  What version of Python are you using?  What documentation are you looking at?  Do you have any code that you've tried so far?

Comment: I followed a tutorial that said to use Replit. I read the documentation from https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#get-channel-message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using discord.py, take a look at [channel.history](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=channel%20history#discord.TextChannel.history)

Comment: I keep getting the error: 

"NameError: name 'channel' is not defined"

Comment: @NinjaNolan Then define it... `channel = ...`